# Pandas Histogram buckets and frequency

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below histogram which I want to plot using pandas

[image]

however it's giving me the below when using

```
dataset.hist(column='frequency')
```

[image]

How would I translate the above into histogram plot?

Per @somiandras answer the plot looks like below:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current plot *is* a histogram, showing the frequency of the values in your `frequency` column.

As you already have the values for the histogram pre-calculated, you don't need `hist`, just index the dataframe with (`range_from`, `range_to`) and plot on a bar plot:

```
dataset.set_index(['range_from', 'range_to'])['frequency'].plot.bar()
```

Comment: indeed it plots the graph but it does not show continuity as a histogram would. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by continuity in this case. Histogram is a discrete plot by definition (it maps a continuous domain to discrete bins), [see this for details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram). Maybe you are looking for a [density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) or the approximation of it by eg. a [kde plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation)? Your pre-calculated data does not really support any of those two.